# Importing covid stats into pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, google-sheets, import

I have been looking for ways to import this Google sheets data into a pandas dataframe without much luck. I have tried all the methods I could find for reading it in and specifying particular pages/sheets, but to me it looks like Google has changed the format since those documents have been written.

I can copy/paste the Google sheet data into Excel and save that as a csv, but that does not seem pythonic.

[Coronavirus numbers by state](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/2/d/e/2PACX-1vRwAqp96T9sYYq2-i7Tj0pvTf6XVHjDSMIKBdZHXiCGGdNC0ypEU9NbngS8mxea55JuCFuua1MUeOj5/pubhtml#)

Comment: `pd.read_excel('file_path.xlsx', sheet_name='State Current')`?

Comment: This isn't an Excel spreadsheet, I am looking to read it in directly from the web.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `pandas`' [`.read_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

Or, in case you want to read it in directly from the cloud, I can really recommend [pygsheets](https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets). It's a great Python API for the Google Sheets API.

Comment: This isn't an Excel spreadsheet, I am looking to read it in directly from the web.

Comment: @shuntera: aha. From your question I understood downloading to file was an option. Edited my answer to suite online access.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this may help if panda will be able to read the url:

[image: 0]